# graphql-ws TypeError: cancellerRef.current is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I got an exception while I am using graphql-ws in my react project

```
Uncaught TypeError: cancellerRef.current is not a function
    at WebSocket.messageListener (graphql-ws.js:431)
    at WebSocket.sentryWrapped (helpers.ts:87)
    at WebSocket.nrWrapper ((index):6)
```

more details

https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/issues/221

I dont know where this error come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it by the upgrade to the latest version of  [graphql-ws](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/releases/tag/v5.3.0)